# Pass two arguments with navigator.notification.confirm?

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-2.0.0

I'm trying to use the Phonegap notification to display an error message in my Phonegap app, and then allow the user to email the error. The only problem is I can't pass the error message to the callback function, rendering the email useless.

The code I have now looks like this:

```
function displayError(errormsg) {
    navigator.notification.confirm(
                                   errormsg,
                                   onConfirm,
                                   'Error',
                                   'Submit, Cancel'
                                   );
}
function onConfirm(buttonIndex){
    if (buttonIndex === 1){
        alert(errormsg);
    }

}
```

Which is called by `displayError("Test")`, which would make the error content `Test`. I want to then pass `errormsg` on to `onConfirm`, but I don't know how to do this, or if it's possible.

A possible solution I was considering was this:

```
function displayError(errormsg) {
    test = errormsg
    navigator.notification.confirm(
                                   errormsg,
                                   onConfirm,
                                   'Error',
                                   'Submit, Cancel'
                                   );
}
function onConfirm(buttonIndex){
    if (buttonIndex === 1){
        alert(test);
    }

}
```

But that doesn't change the `errormsg` if a new error is displayed. I confirmed this because in the simulator setting, my app throws two errors. The first one works fine when using that method, passing on `test`, but then the second error which directly follows uses the original variable, instead of the most recent one.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
function displayError(errormsg) {
    navigator.notification.confirm(
        errormsg,
        function(buttonIndex){
            onConfirm(buttonIndex, errormsg);
        },
        'Error',
        'Submit, Cancel'
        );
}
function onConfirm(buttonIndex, errormsg){
    if (buttonIndex === 1){
        alert(errormsg);
    }

}
```

What about wrapping it in an anonymous function? That way you can pass as many parameters as you like, while maintaining scope.

Comment: this also helps when you need to keep the scope and use `var self = this` instead of `this`. thanks for the idea!

Comment: I wonder why 22 users upvoted this reply but didn't upvote the question. The rating system in this site leaves a lot to be desired...